# Prononciation de "dérailler"

Tags: prononciation

Pourquoi dit-on [deRɑje] au lieu de [deRaje], alors qu'on dit [Raj] pour "rail"? Serait-ce l'influence de "railler" [Rɑje]?

Y a-t-il d'autres exemples semblables?

Je pose cette question en pensant spécialement au Québec, mais les commentaires sur d'autres parties du monde francophone sont bienvenus en autant qu'ils se rapportent à des régions ou des époques où les voyelles [ɑ] et [a] sont ou ont été distinguées nettement.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Pour *rail*, [TLFI](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rail) donne les deux prononciations [ʀɑ:j] et [ʀaj]. Alors, c'est probablement la prononciation de *rail* qui a changé.

Comment: According to wordreference.com, both have the same pronunciation: dérailler is [deʀɑje] (https://www.wordreference.com/fren/d%C3%A9railler) and rail is [ʀɑj] and not [ʀaj] (https://www.wordreference.com/fren/rail)

Answer (score 1):

En France, les deux se prononcent de manière identique.